# BibDesk: trouble adding in .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bibdesk

I am trying to add in a .bib file created by BibDesk to my report. I have saved the .bib file in a different folder. However, it will not import in the typeset.

I tried to follow the Overleaf [instructions](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_4):_Bibliographies_with_BibLaTeX) but when that didn't work, I tried using natbib.

In the preamble, I have included:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\addbibresource{/Users/Jenny/Desktop/EC/Components/References.bib}
```

In the body, I have added in:

```
\bibliography{/Users/Jenny/Desktop/EC/Components/References}
\printbibliography
```

But when I typeset it, my TOC does not come up with the section and the bibliography does not print after the conclusion and before the Appendices.

I would like to also know how to style the bibliography in the Harvard way.

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Jenny

Comment: `\usepackage{cite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` are both incompatible with `biblatex`. But you use `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography`, which are `biblatex` commands. It is not clear from the snippets whether you load `biblatex`.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864

Comment: Any news here? Did you get anywhere with the links?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Your advice was very helpful and it is now working. Thank you very much.